# MVC + FormsAuthentication: Return URL for POST action with AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, authorize

I'm making an event planning website similar to meetup. Guests are welcomed to browse the site and not have to log in util say he clicks on "Join" for an event he's interested in. Because this creates record in database, I have

```
[HttpPost, Authorize]
public RedirectToRoute Join(int id)
```

If an user is not signed in while trying to join an event he is of course redirected to the Sign In page, but how should I handle it after he is authorized? The ReturnURL points to /Event/Join but I can't use Redirect as it's a GET, I'm OK with redirect to event page and have user click "Join" again too but don't want to completely trust Url.Referrer. So what are my options?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Yeah, ended up just having a Get action that redirects to Detail